# Extend maximum duration of stay for a multi-entry Chinese visa (Q2)

Tags: visas, china, multiple-entry, visa-extensions

Taking advantage of the new 10 year visa treaty between USA and China, I applied, and was issued Chinese visa (multiple entry, category Q2). However, I only got approved for 120 days per stay, while I requested 180. My sister, who applied together with me, was approved for 180.

I know I can apply for an extension at the local security bureau, but it seems like one would need to repeat that every time one enters? In the case that I apply for a completely new visa, requesting 180 days, would my old (120 days) visa be cancelled if the new application is not approved, or would I continue to be able to use it? Is there another way I can have the duration of stay extended?

Answer (score 1):

Are u already in China? If you're in Beijing, you need to go to the **Public Security Bureau (PSB)**. Subway line 2, Yonghegong Lama Temple Station, exit gate B and go straight. They can help you with any questions you may have (Went there myself to get an exit permit when my passport was stolen). There are more offices in the big cities. If you're not in China yet, try one of these links:

http://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/extension.htm

http://www.thebeijinger.com/forum/2013/08/02/tips-new-china-visa-policy

chinatravelsavvy.com/visa/china-visa-extensions

onestop.globaltimes.cn/when-and-how-should-i-apply-for-a-visa-extension